# How do I capture the exit codes from $PIPESTATUS and use it to exit the script?

Tags: bash, pipe

I am using $PIPESTATUS to print the exit code for each pipe command. I now know that pipes run in parallel but once the exit code is <>0, how do I get the script to exit instead of progressing to the next command? Thanks.

I can't put set -e at the top because once the error is detected, the script exits but $PIPESTATUS isn't displayed because that echo command is after any failed command in the pipeline.

Comment: Are you thinking of `set -o pipefail` maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exit when one process in pipe fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684119/exit-when-one-process-in-pipe-fails)

Comment: So, when I put set -e at the top of my script, echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" doesn't return any values.

Comment: Pipes don't progress from command to command; all commands run in parallel.

Comment: @chepner I learned this yesterday. I don't want it to exit in the middle of a pipe. But once I capture the exit codes from the entire pipe, and there's an error, I want to exit instead of going to the next line. If I set -e at the top, the script exits before the PIPESTATUS is displayed.

Comment: Don't use `set -e` -- as I advised yesterday, you should implement your own error handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set -o pipefail

true | false | true || { declare -p PIPESTATUS; exit; }
echo "whoops"
```

**output:**

```
declare -a PIPESTATUS=([0]="0" [1]="1" [2]="0")
```

---

From [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> `pipefail`
>
> If set, the return value of a pipeline is the value of the
>   last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if
>   all commands in the pipeline exit successfully. This option is
>   disabled by default.