# Exit tail upon string detection

Tags: bash, pipe, sh, tail, process-substitution

I'm writing a barrier to stall the execution of a script until a certain keyword is logged. The script is pretty simple:

```sh
tail -F -n0 logfile.log | while read LINE; do
    [[ "$LINE" == *'STOP'* ]] && echo ${LINE} && break;
done
```

or

```sh
tail -F -n0 logfile.log | grep -m1 STOP
```

The thing is it doesn't quit as soon as the keyword is detected, but only *after the next line is written*. I.e:

```sh
printf "foo\n"  >> logfile.log  # keeps reading
printf "foo\n"  >> logfile.log  # keeps reading
printf "STOP\n" >> logfile.log  # STOP printed
printf "foo\n"  >> logfile.log  # code exits at last
```

Unfortunately I can't rely on the fact that another line will be logged after the  "STOP" (not within an interval useful for my purposes at least).

The workaround found so far is to `tail` also another file I know for sure gets updated quite frequently, but what is the "clean" solution so that the code will exit right after it logs *STOP*?

Comment: Maybe the process that writes to the log buffers its output?

Comment: maybe, but the line is printed right away, so it's like it gets stuck between the `echo` and the `break`. With a buffer would expect the `echo` to be delayed too

Comment: You only terminate when `tail` tries to write again to the pipe, but since the pipe is broken (because your `while` loop is already terminated) it will crash. It only assesses the condition of the `pipe` when it tries to write to it. don't use a pipe!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), when executing a command of the form

```
command1 | command2
```

and `command2` dies or terminates, the pipe which receives `/dev/stdout` from `command1`  becomes broken. This, however, does not terminate `command1` instantly.

So to achieve what you want is to use *process substitution* and not a pipe

```
awk '/STOP/{exit}1' < <(tail -f logfile)
```

---

When you use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), you can see the behaviour in a bit more detail:

```
$ touch logfile
$ tail -f logfile | awk '/STOP/{exit}1;END{print "end"}'
```

This `awk` program will check if "STOP" is seen, and if not print the line again. If "STOP" is seen it will print "end"

When you do in another terminal

```
$ echo "a" >> logfile
$ echo "STOP" >> logfile
$ echo "b" >> logfile
```

You see that [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) prints the following output:

```
a             # result of print
end           # awk test STOP, exits and executes END statement
```

Furthermore, if you look more closely, you see that [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is at this point already terminated.

*`ps` before sending "STOP":*

```
13625 pts/39   SN     0:00  |        \_ bash
32151 pts/39   SN+    0:00  |            \_ tail -f foo
32152 pts/39   SN+    0:00  |            \_ awk 1;/STOP/{exit}1;END{print "end"}
```

*`ps` after sending "STOP":*

```
13625 pts/39   SN     0:00  |        \_ bash
32151 pts/39   SN+    0:00  |            \_ tail -f foo
```

So the awk program terminated, but `tail` did not crash because it is not yet aware the pipe is broken as it did not attempt to write to it.

When you do the following in the terminal with the pipeline, you see the exit status of `tail`:

```
$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
$ 141 0
```

Which states that `awk` terminated nicely, but `tail` terminated with exit code 141 which means `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: The value of $? following your suggestion `awk '/STOP/{exit}1' < <(tail -f logfile)` seems to not reflect a failure in the tail process itself. For example, if logfile doesn't exist, awk doesn't find the word STOP, and therefore the program terminates successfully. You discuss the different exit codes when using pipes, but could you similarly expand on the different exit codes accessible when using your command substitution example?

Comment: To respond to my own comment, and for others with a similar query, a reasonable workaround is to do `awk '/STOP/{exit}1' < <(tail -f logfile || echo "STOP:$?")`. This means if the tail command fails, the awk process will still find a string that contains STOP, and you can then exit awk with an appropriate exit code to say that the tail command itself failed (or add a little extra processing to forward the precise exit code as parsed from the line that awk reads)