# bash set -e (errexit) only applicable to the last command in a pipeline?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have been reading about bash `set -e` option, and still a bit confused on why the below pipe continues to execute when the file `test-output.xml` does not exist.

Is setting `set -e` only applicable to the exit status of the last command? I can't find this statement (well, explicitly) in the documentation(s) for this option (e.g. [tldp.org -> bash options](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html)).

Thank you for all your help!

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

set -e
fail_tests=`cat test-output.xml|grep '^<testng-results '|perl -e 'print "0";'`
echo $?
echo "fail_tests: [$fail_tests]"
```

outputs:

```
cat: test-output.xml: No such file or directory
0
fail_tests: [0]
```

However, if I change the command to:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

set -e
fail_tests=`cat test-output.xml|grep '^<testng-results '|perl -e 'print "0"; exit 1;'`
echo $?
echo "fail_tests: [$fail_tests]"
```

it outputs:

```
cat: test-output.xml: No such file or directory
```

running with bash version:

```
➜  ~ /usr/local/bin/bash -version
GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Need `pipefail` You want `set -o errexit pipefail`

Comment: Why are you using `cat` with `grep`? Don't [abuse `cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat).

Comment: That said, it's wise to read and fully understand [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) (skipping the allegory for the exercises if in a hurry) before trusting `set -e`.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684119/exit-when-one-process-in-pipe-fails

Comment: @Kulfy You're right, I am just a messenger time [ i.e. this is not my script, however, I was the one debugging :) ]. Regardless, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the exit code of a pipeline is the exit code of the last command in the pipeline. So, by default `set -e` only applies to the last command in each pipeline.

Bash has `set -o pipefail` to extend the behavior or `set -e` to any command in a pipeline.