# How to break pipe if stdin is empty?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, xargs, tee

I want to break the whole pipe if the stdin is empty. I try to combined xargs -r and tee, which means not print and write if stdin is empty, but it failed

`...| upstream commands | xargs -r tee output.txt | downstream commands | ...`

Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Exit when one process in pipe fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684119)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way you can actually terminate a bash pipe conditionally. All commands in a pipeline are started simultaneously. There is however a tool available that would assist you with creating a *conditional* pipeline. In `moreutils` you can find the tool `ifne` which executes a command if and only if the input `/dev/stdin` is not empty. So you could write something like:

```
$ command1 | ifne command2 | ifne command3 | ifne command4
```

Here all commands `ifne` and `command1` are started simultaniously. Only if `ifne` receives input via `/dev/stdin`, it will start its respective `commandx`

Answer (score 3):

Pipe'll break if command failed. You can add grep in between to achieve this. An example:

```
$ echo ok | awk '{print $0,"1"}' | awk '{print $0,"2"}' | awk '{print $0,"3"}'
ok 1 2 3
```

Now add grep:

```
$ echo ok | grep -Ei '^.+$' | awk '{print $0,"1"}' | awk '{print $0,"2"}' | awk '{print $0,"3"}'
ok 1 2 3
```

And test empty echo:

```
$ echo | awk '{print $0,"1"}' | awk '{print $0,"2"}' | awk '{print $0,"3"}'
 1 2 3

$ echo | grep -Ei '^.+$' | awk '{print $0,"1"}' | awk '{print $0,"2"}' | awk '{print $0,"3"}'
```

Looks like this works but it doesn't, interesting indeed, well then obvy pipes don't fit here, try this approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

fun(){
    data=$(echo "$1"); [[ $data ]] && data=$(awk '{print $0,1}' <<< "$data") || return 1; [[ $data ]] && data=$(awk '{print $0,2}' <<< "$data") || return 1; [[ $data ]] && data=$(awk '{print $0,3}' <<< "$data") || return 1; echo "$data"
}

fun ok
fun
```

Testing:

```
$ ./test 
+ fun ok
++ echo ok
+ data=ok
+ [[ -n ok ]]
++ awk '{print $0,1}'
+ data='ok 1'
+ [[ -n ok 1 ]]
++ awk '{print $0,2}'
+ data='ok 1 2'
+ [[ -n ok 1 2 ]]
++ awk '{print $0,3}'
+ data='ok 1 2 3'
+ echo 'ok 1 2 3'
ok 1 2 3
+ fun
++ echo ''
+ data=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ return 1
```

More readable variant:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

fun(){
        data=$(echo "$1")
    [[ $data ]] && data=$(awk '{print $0,1}' <<< "$data") || return 1
    [[ $data ]] && data=$(awk '{print $0,2}' <<< "$data") || return 1
    [[ $data ]] && data=$(awk '{print $0,3}' <<< "$data") || return 1
        echo     "$data"
}

fun ok
fun
```

Comment: This does not break the pipe, it still executes each command. The idea is not to execute the commands

Comment: As @kvantour said, actually I want to break the following commands if the last stdout is empty, so as to avoid to generated a lot of empty file by tee in a loop.